# php SQL statements don't work, but when I try to use statements in a DBMS, they do work

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, insert

The following is the php code I'm working on and the insert query seems to work when I put it into phpMyAdmin (using XAMPP), but $status returns false for some reason when running the query here...I've tried every combination of changing the Insert statement and doing file output checks to see where the issue is coming from but am completely stumped as of now. Any ideas?

```
function addQuestion($question_to_add) {

    global $host, $username, $password, $dbName, $user_table, $registered_user_table, $question_table;
    global $answer_table, $user_answer, $user_post;


    connectToDB($username, $password, $host, $dbName);

    //$countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(QID) FROM questions";
    //$count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($countQuery))[0];//we fetch an array of counts for each column and return the count of column 0

    $addQuestionQuery = "INSERT INTO questions (QID, UID, title, _timestamp, numRating, content, category, location) VALUES (0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)";
    $status = mysql_query($addQuestionQuery);

    if ($status == false) {// if the query failed, for whatever reason, let us know.
        file_put_contents("out","false");
        return false;
    }
    file_put_contents("out","true");
    return true;
}
```

Useful:

```
function connectToDB($user, $password, $server_host, $db_name) {

    $conn = mysql_connect($server_host, $user. $password);

    if (!$conn) {

        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        //
    } 


    mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn);

}
```

Comment: Use [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/mysql_error) to get the reason for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong parameter on the connection:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server_host, $user. $password);
                                        ^ . it should be ,
```

Note: Use the better version which is mysqli or PDO. Mysql is now deprecated and no longer maintained.

And as always, when debugging, always turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
mysql_error();
```